# Pattern matching unknown name for positional sub-patterns

Tags: python, pattern-matching

```
import itertools

a = itertools.product('1', '123')

match a:
  case itertools.product('1', '123'):
    print(list(a))
```

gives,

```
TypeError: itertools.product() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (2 given)
```

a similar error occurs for,

```
from fractions import Fraction

frctn = Fraction(1, 2)

match frctn:
  case Fraction(1, 2):
    print(1)
```

in this case, one could solve the error by specifying
`case Fraction(numerator=1, denominator=2):`

but how does one solve this error for the `itertools.product` case?

Answer (score 0):

You need a list argument:

```
a = itertools.product(['1', '123'])
```

`product` takes items in a list and multiplies them in all possible combinations.